# If object property have same id, push into new array

Tags: javascript

I would like to push the names into an new object if they have the same Id. The solution is not there yet, but I'm getting closer

```
const names = [
{id:1,name:"jame"},
{id:2,name:"jill"},
{id:3,name:"hanna"},
{id:3,name:"clark"}
]

const newNames = []
// Something like this
names.foreach((person,index) => {
 if(newNames[index].id === person.id){
 newNames.push({id:person.index, names:[...newNames.name,person.name]})
 }else{
 newNames.push({id:person.index, person.name})
 }
})
```

The outcome would look something like this:

```
const newNames = [
{id:1,name:"jame"},
{id:2,name:"jill"},
{id:3,names: {name:"clark",name:"hanna"}}
]
```

Issue: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Comment: And the actual (ignoring the typo in `names.foreach()`) problem is? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
const names = [
    {id:1,name:"jame"},
    {id:2,name:"jill"},
    {id:3,name:"hanna"},
    {id:3,name:"clark"}
];

let output = []
let ids = [...new Set(names.map(i=>i.id))];
ids.forEach((id) => {
    let res = names.filter((name) => name.id == id)
    output.push({id, name: res.length > 1 ?
        res.map(i => i.name) :
        res[0].name})
})
console.log(output)
```

Note I have given an array for the `name` attribute for entries with multiple names to be less repetitive.

---

Going along with your solution:

```
names.forEach((person,index) => {
    let existingIndex = newNames.findIndex( (entry) => entry.id === person.id)
    if(existingIndex >= 0){
        if(newNames[existingIndex].hasOwnProperty('name'))
            newNames[existingIndex] = ({id: person.id, names: [newNames[existingIndex].name,person.name]})
        else
            newNames[existingIndex] = ({id: person.id, names: [...newNames[existingIndex].names,person.name]})
     } else {
        newNames.push({id:person.id, name: person.name})
      }
})
```

The part `newNames[index].id` in your original solution results in an error because newNames does not have any elements so far. So basically newNames[0] results in `undefined`.